# C# Socket Server not have more 800 clients

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking

I have C# socket sever. Max clients count who able to connect with server about 800. If clients more then 800 new clients get socket error WSAECONNREFUSED 10061. 
How raizeup max clients count?

Socket write between socket.BeginXXX and socket.EndXXX. Target: framework 4.0. Protocols: IP4, TCP

Comment: Sounds like the listener queue is full.  Can you paste some code?

Comment: A router or a firewall can also limit the range of available ports.

Comment: @Groo there is only one port in play here, the port the server is listening on.

Answer (score 4):

The listener backlog queue is full. When the backlog queue is full Windows will start sending RSTs to further incoming connections, which become 'connection refused' at the client(s) concerned. You can raise the backlog queue length as per other answers here, but what it really means is that you aren't processing accepts fast enough. Take a good look at the code that does that, and grease the path. Make sure it doesn't do anything *else*, such as blocking I/O, disk I/O, other network operations. Once the connection is accepted it is off the backlog queue so other incoming connections can succeed.

Answer (score 2):

When setting the serversocket to its listen state you can set the backlog. That is the maximum number of connections that can be waiting to be accepted.

Everything else is possibly a hardware issue - try running the program on a different machine.

Here is an example of a

```
Socket serversocket = ...
serversocket.Listen(1000);
```

Comment: Hardware issue how? How can the hardware cause TCP resets and refused connections?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of the network cards. Its an hypothetical that may be completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Hi i find answer on my question. I create additional thread for accept connection. For example:

Previous

```
IPEndPoint myEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(_serverAddress), _port);
 _serverSocket = new Socket(myEndpoint.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

 _serverSocket.Bind(myEndpoint);
 _serverSocket.Listen((int)SocketOptionName.MaxConnections);

_serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), _serverSocket);

.....


private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            ConnectionInfo connection = new ConnectionInfo();
            try
            {
                Socket s = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
                connection.Socket = s.EndAccept(result);

                connection.Buffer = new byte[1024];
                connection.Socket.BeginReceive(connection.Buffer,
                    0, connection.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback),
                    connection);
            }
            catch (SocketException exc)
            {
                CloseConnection(connection, "Exception in Accept");
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                CloseConnection(connection, "Exception in Accept");
            }
            finally
            {

                    _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), result.AsyncState);
            }
        }
```

By this way client connection count no raize 800

Currently i write this:

```
 IPEndPoint myEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(_serverAddress), _port);
 _serverSocket = new Socket(myEndpoint.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

 _serverSocket.Bind(myEndpoint);
 _serverSocket.Listen((int)SocketOptionName.MaxConnections);

acceptThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ExecuteAccept));
acceptThread.Start();

......

private void ExecuteAccept()
        {

            while (true)
            {

                ConnectionInfo connection = new ConnectionInfo();
                try
                {
                    connection.Socket = _serverSocket.Accept();

                    connection.Buffer = new byte[1024];
                    connection.Socket.BeginReceive(connection.Buffer, 0, connection.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), connection);
                }
                catch (SocketException exc)
                {
                    CloseConnection(connection, "Exception in Accept");
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    CloseConnection(connection, "Exception in Accept");
                }
            }
        }
```

By this way client connection count raize over 2000. Read and write i do with BeginXXX and EndXXX.

Comment: I'm so confused could someone shed more light on this... if i have a loop which creates 1000 connections to the listener... why would i get "Additional information: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" when there is a backlog of like MaxConnectoins = 2147483647... how do i code to monitor this on the listener... ie how do i know when the listener will reject connections... asuming that is what it is doing.Error code 10061 plz help thx